# cURL or wget for measuring page load time?

Tags: windows, curl, wget, pageload

What's the best/most accurate way to measure a pages load time that would include the time to load all of the pages resources? (Basically trying to get a load time that a real end user might have).

Is it better to use Wget or cURL for this type of task? (The operating system in use will be Windows due to other dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download all the resources requested by a page with `wget`, using the `-p` option:

```bash
wget -p https://www.example.com/
```

`curl` doesn't parse HTML so it can't be used for this. It will just print the initial page's HTML but if the HTML requests images or CSS or JS files, it won't know about that (because it doesn't parse HTML) so it won't download any of them.

`wget` won't be a very accurate measure of the page's load time if the page requests resources through JavaScript, because `wget` doesn't parse or execute JavaScript. A more accurate way to get user perceived load times is to open the page in Chrome and then look at how long it took. You can see an accurate breakdown by looking at the Network tab in the Dev Tools. If you're trying to automate it, you can use Chrome Headless through Puppeteer, something like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  // Get the first tab
  const page = (await browser.pages())[0];

  await page.goto('https://example.com/');
  const loadTime = page.evaluate(() => window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart);
  console.log(loadTime);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

This on its own will also not be accurate due to caching of DNS results, the TLS handshake or resources by the browser.

Comment: If I wasn't after the most accurate load time in general, but just as a measure to test some of my software that impacts the network, would using Virtual Machines with identical configurations and Selenium (or Puppeteer) result in getting comparable load times? As in could I use those load times to accurately compare how different versions of my software affect the network/page load times?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

If you only get the page load time, you cannot accomplish what you want to do. At a minimum, you need *"Time to First Byte"* to eliminate Server delays from performance issues.

WebPageTest has a LOT of data. But what I use is minimal.  The below example, the JSON file has 162,260 lines of JSON (5.5 MB), I use 125 lines (4 KB) of it.

To show you how easy it is, I wrote this PHP app in a couple of hours.
I entered a URL at https://www.webpagetest.org
I copied the "Download JSON" link
Pasted it into my PHP code
The code,
Retrieved the JSON
Got a sub string of the JSON I needed.
Then formatted the data
And made a table
I just used a few parameters that would be needed to assess performance.
I included the Number of DOM elements and JS & CSS Blocking because those are very common issues with many pages,  especially WordPress pages.

I find the layout shift to be important.  Layout shift is when after the first paint, JS makes a change that requires the Browser to do another rendering.

[image: WebPageSpeedTest JSON Link]

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; UTF-8");

$data = file_get_contents('https://www.webpagetest.org/jsonResult.php?test=<result id>&pretty=1');
$start = strpos($data,'chromeUserTiming.CumulativeLayoutShift": ') + 41;

$LayoutShift = substr($data,$start,6);
$start = strpos($data,'"firstView": {') + 13;

$end = strpos($data,'}',$start) + 1;
$json = substr($data,$start,$end - $start);
unset($data);
$json = json_decode($json,1);
$TTFB = number_format($json['TTFB'] / 1000,3); 
$loadTime = number_format($json['loadTime'] / 1000,3);
$fullyLoaded = number_format($json['fullyLoaded'] / 1000,3);
$loadEventStart = number_format($json['loadEventStart'] / 1000,3);
$firstPaint = number_format($json['firstPaint'] / 1000,3);
$firstContentfulPaint = number_format($json['firstContentfulPaint'] / 1000,3);
$renderBlockingCSS = number_format($json['renderBlockingCSS'] / 1000,3);
$renderBlockingJS = number_format($json['renderBlockingJS'] / 1000,3);
$TotalBlockingTime = number_format($json['TotalBlockingTime'] / 1000,3);
$FirstInteractive = number_format($json['FirstInteractive'] / 1000,3);
$fullyLoaded = number_format($json['fullyLoaded'] / 1000,3);
$TotalBlockingTime = number_format($json['TotalBlockingTime'] / 1000,3);
$renderBlockingCSS = number_format($json['renderBlockingCSS'] / 1000,3);
$renderBlockingJS = number_format($json['renderBlockingJS'] / 1000,3);
$requests = $json['requests'] ;
$domElements = $json['domElements'] ;
$domComplete = number_format($json['domComplete'] / 1000,3);
$LayoutShift = number_format($json['chromeUserTiming.TotalLayoutShift'] / 1000,3);
echo <<<EOT
<table>
<tr><td>First Byte</td><td>$TTFB</td></tr>
<tr><td>DOM Complete</td><td>$domComplete</td></tr>
<tr><td>Load Time</td><td>$loadTime</td></tr>
<tr><td>First Paint</td><td>$firstPaint </td></tr>
<tr><td>Fully Loaded</td><td>$fullyLoaded</td></tr>
<tr><td></td> <td></td> </tr>
<tr><td></td> <td></td> </tr>
<tr><td>Requests</td><td>$requests</td></tr>
<tr><td>DOM Elements</td><td>$domElements</td></tr>
<tr><td>CSS Render Blocking</td><td>$renderBlockingCSS</td></tr>
<tr><td>JS Render Blocking</td><td>$renderBlockingJS</td></tr>
<tr><td>Total Blocking Time</td><td>$TotalBlockingTime </td></tr>
<tr><td>Layout Shift</td><td>$LayoutShift </td></tr>
</table
EOT;
?>
```

**The results**
These results are for a mobile page with lots of pictures.
For mobile I like to have as few requests as possible. 
I embed the images in the page as base64.

[image: Page Speed Performance Results]

**This is the sub string of the JSON I actually use:**

```
{
"loadTime": 580.33333333333337,
"docTime": 580.33333333333337,
"fullyLoaded": 640.33333333333337,
"bytesOut": 3480,
"bytesOutDoc": 3114.6666666666665,
"bytesIn": 117909,
"bytesInDoc": 117862.66666666667,
"requests": 3,
"requestsFull": 3,
"requestsDoc": 2.6666666666666665,
"responses_200": 3,
"responses_404": 0,
"responses_other": 0,
"result": 0,
"testStartOffset": 0,
"cached": 0,
"optimization_checked": 1,
"loadEventStart": 575.33333333333337,
"loadEventEnd": 575.66666666666663,
"domContentLoadedEventStart": 510.33333333333331,
"domContentLoadedEventEnd": 510.33333333333331,
"connections": 1,
"final_base_page_request": 0,
"firstPaint": 304.63333333283333,
"firstContentfulPaint": 309.66666666666669,
"firstImagePaint": 309.66666666666669,
"firstMeaningfulPaint": 309.66666666666669,
"domInteractive": 510.33333333333331,
"renderBlockingCSS": 0,
"renderBlockingJS": 0,
"TTFB": 264.66666666666669,
"score_cache": 0,
"score_cdn": 0,
"score_gzip": 100,
"score_cookies": -1,
"score_keep-alive": 100,
"score_minify": -1,
"score_combine": -1,
"score_compress": 100,
"score_etags": -1,
"score_progressive_jpeg": -1,
"gzip_total": 118336,
"gzip_savings": 0,
"minify_total": -1,
"minify_savings": -1,
"image_total": 1667,
"image_savings": 0,
"cpu.PrePaint": 1,
"cpu.Paint": 2.6666666666666665,
"cpu.FireAnimationFrame": 0,
"cpu.FunctionCall": 5.333333333333333,
"cpu.EventDispatch": 0.66666666666666663,
"cpu.CommitLoad": 0,
"cpu.EvaluateScript": 1.3333333333333333,
"cpu.v8.compile": 0.33333333333333331,
"cpu.ParseHTML": 7,
"cpu.ResourceFetcher::requestResource": 8.3333333333333339,
"cpu.UpdateLayoutTree": 9.6666666666666661,
"cpu.Layout": 17.333333333333332,
"cpu.largestContentfulPaint::Candidate": 0,
"cpu.HitTest": 0,
"cpu.MarkDOMContent": 0,
"cpu.MarkLoad": 0,
"cpu.Idle": 586.33333333333337,
"start_epoch": 1666370740.1789024,
"date": 1666370741.9859715,
"fullyLoadedCPUms": 670,
"fullyLoadedCPUpct": 9.1036962354000011,
"domElements": 75,
"domComplete": 575.33333333333337,
"PerformancePaintTiming.first-paint": 304.63333333283333,
"PerformancePaintTiming.first-contentful-paint": 304.63333333283333,
"test_run_time_ms": 5673.333333333333,
"Colordepth": 24,
"generated-content-percent": -0.029999999999999999,
"generated-content-size": -0.040000000000000001,
"lastVisualChange": 400,
"render": 300,
"visualComplete85": 300,
"visualComplete90": 300,
"visualComplete95": 300,
"visualComplete99": 400,
"visualComplete": 400,
"SpeedIndex": 303,
"chromeUserTiming.navigationStart": 5.333333333333333,
"chromeUserTiming.fetchStart": 8.3333333333333339,
"chromeUserTiming.unloadEventStart": 275.66666666666669,
"chromeUserTiming.unloadEventEnd": 275.66666666666669,
"chromeUserTiming.commitNavigationEnd": 276,
"chromeUserTiming.domLoading": 276.33333333333331,
"chromeUserTiming.firstPaint": 309,
"chromeUserTiming.firstContentfulPaint": 309,
"chromeUserTiming.firstImagePaint": 309.33333333333331,
"chromeUserTiming.firstMeaningfulPaintCandidate": 309.33333333333331,
"chromeUserTiming.firstMeaningfulPaint": 309.33333333333331,
"chromeUserTiming.responseEnd": 510.33333333333331,
"chromeUserTiming.domInteractive": 515.66666666666663,
"chromeUserTiming.domContentLoadedEventStart": 515.66666666666663,
"chromeUserTiming.domContentLoadedEventEnd": 515.66666666666663,
"chromeUserTiming.domComplete": 580,
"chromeUserTiming.loadEventStart": 580.33333333333337,
"chromeUserTiming.loadEventEnd": 580.66666666666663,
"chromeUserTiming.LargestTextPaint": 309.66666666666669,
"chromeUserTiming.LargestImagePaint": 309.66666666666669,
"chromeUserTiming.LargestContentfulPaint": 309.66666666666669,
"chromeUserTiming.TotalLayoutShift": 0.0011286408333333333,
"chromeUserTiming.CumulativeLayoutShift": 0.0011286408333333333,
"TTIMeasurementEnd": 3657.3333333333335,
"LastInteractive": 300,
"run": 2,
"step": 1,
"effectiveBps": 313879.33333333331,
"domTime": 0,
"aft": 0,
"titleTime": 293.33333333333331,
"domLoading": 0,
"server_rtt": 0,
"maxFID": 0,
"TotalBlockingTime": 0,
"effectiveBpsDoc": 373405.33333333331,
"chromeUserTiming.LayoutShift": 109,
"avgRun": 3
}
```

### I also use GT Metrix

[image]

### And PageSpeed Insights

[image]

### And W3C Validators,  both HTML and CSS

[image: w3c CSS valadator]

**End of Update**

---

---

You can use curl to get the response time for the HTML.  It will not give you much more.

curl will give you:

```
CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD - Total number of bytes uploaded
CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD - Total number of bytes downloaded
CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD - Average download speed
CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD - Average upload speed
```

The best way I know of to get EVERY detail of an HTTP request is to use https://www.webpagetest.org
You can use their API to get 300 performance test results per month for Free.

[LINK to webpagetest.org API](https://docs.webpagetest.org/api/)

**Example**
You curl the API and it returns the links to the details.  Within those links there is a plethora of information and images. 
Then curl the links you want.

[LINK to HAR details of loading this page. 110,000 lines of info in 6,795,929 bytes](https://www.webpagetest.org/export.php?bodies=1&pretty=1&test=221020_AiDc05_4BQ)

```
curl https://www.webpagetest.org/runtest.php?url=https://www.webpagetest.org&k={YOUR_API_KEY}&f=json

{
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusText": "Ok",
      "data": {
         "testId": "210328_XiVQ_b694021b2a24ca1912dae50fb58b5861",
         "jsonUrl": "https://www.webpagetest.org/jsonResult.php?test=210328_XiVQ_b694021b2a24ca1912dae50fb58b5861",
         "xmlUrl": "https://www.webpagetest.org/xmlResult/210328_XiVQ_b694021b2a24ca1912dae50fb58b5861/",
         "userUrl": "https://www.webpagetest.org/result/210328_XiVQ_b694021b2a24ca1912dae50fb58b5861/",
         "summaryCSV": "https://www.webpagetest.org/result/210328_XiVQ_b694021b2a24ca1912dae50fb58b5861/page_data.csv",
         "detailCSV": "https://www.webpagetest.org/result/210328_XiVQ_b694021b2a24ca1912dae50fb58b5861/requests.csv"
      }
}
```

The waterfall below shows some of the details you can get. 
You can get the nitty gritty details in various formats:

- JSON
- CSV
- XML
- HAR

[image: Waterfall for this page from webpagetest.org]

**Sample of CSV info**

```
"type","id","request_id","ip_addr","full_url","is_secure","method","host","url","raw_id","frame_id","documentURL","responseCode","request_type","load_ms","ttfb_ms","load_start","load_start_float","bytesIn","objectSize","objectSizeUncompressed","expires","cacheControl","contentType","contentEncoding","socket","protocol","dns_start","dns_end","connect_start","connect_end","ssl_start","ssl_end","initiator","initiator_line","initiator_column","initiator_type","priority","initial_priority","server_rtt","bytesOut","score_cache","score_cdn","score_gzip","score_cookies","score_keep-alive","score_minify","score_combine","score_compress","score_etags","dns_ms","connect_ms","ssl_ms","gzip_total","gzip_save","minify_total","minify_save","image_total","image_save","cache_time","cdn_provider","server_count","created","http2_stream_id","http2_stream_dependency","http2_stream_weight","http2_stream_exclusive","tls_version","tls_resumed","tls_next_proto","tls_cipher_suite","netlog_id","server_port","final_base_page","is_base_page","load_end","ttfb_start","ttfb_end","download_start","download_end","download_ms","all_start","all_end","all_ms","index","number","cpu.EvaluateScript","cpu.v8.compile","cpu.FunctionCall","cpuTime","run","cached","renderBlocking","initiator_function",
"3","221020_AiDc05_4BQ","BE8FE33DABBBA0CF2B3AC5D78083C66E","151.101.193.69","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","1","GET","stackoverflow.com","/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","BE8FE33DABBBA0CF2B3AC5D78083C66E","4476133D5C5FF9920B0E2BB49084B133","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","200","Document","346","198","533","533.000041","40562","40562","145896","","private","text/html","gzip","50","HTTP/2","0","172","173","344","344","533","","","","script","Highest","Highest","","2317","-1","100","100","-1","100","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","171","189","41099","0","","","","","","Fastly","","4","1","0","256","1","TLS 1.2","False","h2","49199","41","443","1","1","879","533","731","731","879","148","173","879","706","0","1","135","26","2","164","1","0","","",
"3","221020_AiDc05_4BQ","6487.6","151.101.193.69","https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=0e3ada576039","1","GET","cdn.sstatic.net","/Js/stub.en.js?v=0e3ada576039","6487.6","4476133D5C5FF9920B0E2BB49084B133","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","200","Script","585","568","967","967.000067","18152","18152","53336","","max-age=604800","application/javascript","gzip","50","HTTP/2","787","967","-1","-1","-1","-1","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","25","","parser","High","High","","1831","50","100","100","-1","100","-1","-1","-1","-1","180","-1","-1","18152","0","","","","","34541","Fastly","","788","9","","","","","","","","67","","","","1552","967","1535","1535","1552","17","787","1552","765","1","2","34","8","443","485","1","0","blocking","",
"3","221020_AiDc05_4BQ","6487.5","151.101.193.69","https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/npm/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/js/stacks.min.js?v=facbc6b2f3b6","1","GET","cdn.sstatic.net","/Js/third-party/npm/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/js/stacks.min.js?v=facbc6b2f3b6","6487.5","4476133D5C5FF9920B0E2BB49084B133","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","200","Script","599","568","968","968.000061","23746","23746","100193","","max-age=604800","application/javascript","gzip","50","HTTP/2","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","24","","parser","Low","Low","","1978","50","100","100","-1","100","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","23746","0","","","","","567498","Fastly","","786","11","","","","","","","","61","","","","1567","968","1536","1536","1567","31","968","1567","599","2","3","81","2","38","121","1","0","potentially_blocking","",
"3","221020_AiDc05_4BQ","6487.7","151.101.193.69","https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=5ad0f45f4799","1","GET","cdn.sstatic.net","/Shared/stacks.css?v=5ad0f45f4799","6487.7","4476133D5C5FF9920B0E2BB49084B133","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","200","Stylesheet","363","188","968","968.000072","68692","68692","654577","","max-age=604800","text/css","gzip","50","HTTP/2","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","28","","parser","Highest","Highest","","1885","50","100","100","-1","100","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","68692","0","","","","","542107","Fastly","","790","3","","","","","","","","72","","","","1331","968","1156","1156","1331","175","968","1331","363","3","4","","","","","1","0","blocking","",
"3","221020_AiDc05_4BQ","6487.8","151.101.193.69","https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=0cc30ee01b86","1","GET","cdn.sstatic.net","/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=0cc30ee01b86","6487.8","4476133D5C5FF9920B0E2BB49084B133","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","200","Stylesheet","550","374","968","968.000077","60467","60467","339815","","max-age=604800","text/css","gzip","50","HTTP/2","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","29","","parser","Highest","Highest","","1927","50","100","100","-1","100","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","60467","0","","","","","134559","Fastly","","793","5","","","","","","","","77","","","","1518","968","1342","1342","1518","176","968","1518","550","4","5","","","","","1","0","blocking","",
"3","221020_AiDc05_4BQ","6487.9","151.101.193.69","https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/Channels/channels.css?v=d098999fc478","1","GET","cdn.sstatic.net","/Shared/Channels/channels.css?v=d098999fc478","6487.9","4476133D5C5FF9920B0E2BB49084B133","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","200","Stylesheet","551","393","968","968.000082","4168","4168","18913","","max-age=604800","text/css","gzip","50","HTTP/2","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","70","","parser","Highest","Highest","","1918","50","100","100","-1","100","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","4168","0","","","","","477490","Fastly","","797","7","","","","","","","","82","","","","1519","968","1361","1361","1519","158","968","1519","551","5","6","","","","","1","0","blocking","",
"3","221020_AiDc05_4BQ","6487.4","142.251.163.95","https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js","1","GET","ajax.googleapis.com","/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js","6487.4","4476133D5C5FF9920B0E2BB49084B133","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","200","Script","370","175","1309","1309.000055","33951","33951","97163","Thu, 19 Oct 2023 17:18:45 GMT","public, max-age=31536000, stale-while-revalidate=2592000","text/javascript","gzip","87","HTTP/2","784","955","955","1128","1128","1309","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","23","","parser","High","High","","1870","100","100","100","-1","100","-1","-1","-1","-1","171","173","181","33951","0","","","","","31493759","Google","","783","1","0","220","1","TLS 1.3","False","h2","4865","55","443","","","1679","1309","1484","1484","1679","195","784","1679","895","6","7","64","12","31","107","1","0","blocking","",
"3","221020_AiDc05_4BQ","6487.10","151.101.193.69","https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e","1","GET","cdn.sstatic.net","/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg?v=47faa659a05e","6487.10","4476133D5C5FF9920B0E2BB49084B133","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","200","Image","176","175","1580","1580.000099","2368","2368","5950","","max-age=604800","image/svg+xml","gzip","50","HTTP/2","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","485","","parser","Low","Low","","2101","50","100","100","-1","100","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","2368","0","","","","","93767","Fastly","","1579","13","0","147","1","","","","","99","443","","","1756","1580","1755","1755","1756","1","1580","1756","176","7","8","","","","","1","0","","",
"3","221020_AiDc05_4BQ","6487.20","151.101.193.69","https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27","1","GET","cdn.sstatic.net","/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27","6487.20","4476133D5C5FF9920B0E2BB49084B133","https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122109/curl-or-wget-for-measuring-page-load-time","200","Image","176","174","2163","2163.000126","2852","2852","7542","","max-age=604800","image/svg+xml","gzip","50","HTTP/2","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=0cc30ee01b86","","","parser","High","Low","","2173","50","100","100","-1","100","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","2852","0","","","","","383944","Fastly","","2162","15","0","147","1","","","","","126","443","","","2339","2163","2337","2337","2339","2","2163","2339","176","8","9","","","","","1","0","","",
```

The CSV contains the following details on every request made to render the page.

```
type
id
request_id
ip_addr
full_url
is_secure
method
host
url
raw_id
frame_id
documentURL
responseCode
request_type
load_ms
ttfb_ms
load_start
load_start_float
bytesIn
objectSize
objectSizeUncompressed
expires
cacheControl
contentType
contentEncoding
socket
protocol
dns_start
dns_end
connect_start
connect_end
ssl_start
ssl_end
initiator
initiator_line
initiator_column
initiator_type
priority
initial_priority
server_rtt
bytesOut
score_cache
score_cdn
score_gzip
score_cookies
score_keep-alive
score_minify
score_combine
score_compress
score_etags
dns_ms
connect_ms
ssl_ms
gzip_total
gzip_save
minify_total
minify_save
image_total
image_save
cache_time
cdn_provider
server_count
created
http2_stream_id
http2_stream_dependency
http2_stream_weight
http2_stream_exclusive
tls_version
tls_resumed
tls_next_proto
tls_cipher_suite
netlog_id
server_port
final_base_page
is_base_page
load_end
ttfb_start
ttfb_end
download_start
download_end
download_ms
all_start
all_end
all_ms
index
number
cpu.EvaluateScript
cpu.v8.compile
cpu.FunctionCall
cpuTime
run
cached
renderBlocking
initiator_function
```